# How to completely remove or reduce the app launch delay to 1 or 2sec for an Ionic app

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I am building an Ionic app in V1.

I want to reduce the app launch delay to 1 or 2seconds maximum. I will be okay even if there is NO delay as I don't want any splash screen to be shown.

Tried all the solutions like --prod, --aot, splashscreen preferences in config.xml.

Please let me know if it is possible to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for the splash screen plugin

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/

You can set these preferences in your config.xml

SplashScreenDelay (number, default to 3000). Amount of time in milliseconds to wait before automatically hide splash screen.

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

To disable the splashscreen add the following preference to config.xml:

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
```